# .net regex group that doesn't appear in matches

Tags: .net, html, regex

is there a way to group a matching element but not have that match appear in the resulting match groups? for example, suppose I have a string with two lines:

```
<td>text 1</td>
<td><a href=whatever>this is</a> text 2</td>
```

and I want to parse out "text 1" and "this is text 2". what I'm doing now is using this pattern:

```
<td>(<a href=.+?>)?(.+?(</a>)?.+?)</td>
```

basically grouping the anchor tags so I can have the pattern match them zero or one time. I don't want those groups to appear in the match results (though I can easily ignore them). is there a proper way to do this?

Comment: Regular expressions are insufficient for what you are trying to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a non-capturing group:

```
(?:xxx)
```

A non-capturing group works like a normal group in that you can use operators on it.  But it does not capture anything, and you can't use it for backreferences.

Comment: thanks, that's what I need. but it looks like it doesn't do what I want if I nest a non-capturing group inside a capturing group...is that not possible?

Comment: specifically for the second example, if I match with:

<td>(?:<a href=.+?>)(.+?(?:</a>).+?)</td>

it doesn't properly match the </a>

Comment: In the regex in your comment, `a href` is not optional. Try `<td>(?:<a href=.+?>)?(.+?(?:</a>)?.+?)</td>` instead.  BTW-- if you're parsing HTML, a regex is a pretty bad approach.  Try this instead http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack